# JavaScript: use .map() and .forEach() on new Array() of undefinded

Tags: javascript, arrays

If I have the following:

```js
const array = new Array(5)
console.log(array)

array.forEach(() => console.log('Hello')) // does not work
```

I would expect to see 5 'Hellos', but it seems JS doesn't even get into the loop. Why?

What I was trying to accomplish was initializing an array of objects like the following:

```js
const users = (new Array(5)).map(() => ({name:''}))

console.log(users)
```

Comment: "*What I was trying to accomplish was initializing an array of objects like the following:*" then use `Array.from({length: 5}, () => ({name:''}))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```js
const result = Array.apply(null, new Array(5)).map(() => ({name:''}));
console.log(result);
```

Or this:

```js
const result = [...new Array(5)].map(() => ({name:''}));
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 2):

`.map` and `.foEach` loop over each item in the Array, by doing `new Array(5)` you get an array of length 5, but it's empty, nothing to loop over, you still need to fill it with items

Comment: would you recommend doing this?  const names = [...new Array(5)].map( () => ({name:''}))

Answer (score 1):

You can fill your array like:

```
const array = new Array(5).fill({ name: '' });
```

Comment: no. you get the same object at every index.

Comment: You are right @Zac, I get the same object. This would be perfect for primitive values.